# Would translation issues count as "behind-the-scenes"?

Tags: discussion, scope, language

I was thinking of asking about how the poem about Samson in Stanislaw Lem's *The Cyberiad* was translated, given the extremely specific constraints for the poem. However, after a modest amount of research I discovered the answer.

Would such a question be considered as on-topic? It seems to *somewhat* fit "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information".

If it is on-topic, I might post the question and the answer. (There might be others who were curious about how the translation was possible, and the answer was not quite a case of Let Me Google That For You.)

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

It's hard to be certain without knowing what the full question is, but there's nothing inherently off topic here.